# Existing HTML website, but processing on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I have a website hosted already and it contains an HTML form. I want to be able to submit the form to a Python script on Google App engine to handle the data. In the documentation, there is a tutorial to process forms with Python, but it was from a page that was served in the script itself. How do I link an existing domain/webpage to a script running on Google App Engine? Thanks for any help!

~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a post request to whatever http resource you want

in your html form you can change the `action` to point at your gae python script

`<form action="http://yourdomain/your/gae/endpoint" method="post">`

You can then follow the tutorial and access the posted data accordingly.  Finally, it is up to you to return an appropriate response, this might include redirecting back to the original domain, dependent on your application

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So I'm assuming this uses rest http on the serverside?